# Gaussian distribution function different answer for program and math

Tags: java, machine-learning, gaussian

I write down a code to implement Gaussian distribution function.

The code block

```
import java.lang.Math.*;
public class gauss {
public static void main(String args[]){

    gauss c = new gauss();
    c.gu1(5.0,3.0,2.0);



}
public static double gu1(double mu,double sigm2,double x)
{
    double a;
    
    a=1/(Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI))*sigm2;
    double b;
    
    b= Math.exp(-0.5)*(Math.pow(((x-mu)/sigm2)),2);
    double z= a*b;
    System.out.println(z);
    return(z);
    }
}
```

Input: x = 2, μ = 5 and σ = 3
Output: 0.7259121735574301

However, if I solve it mathematically using pen and paper I got 0.0805 as answer.

I did not find out why there is such a difference with programming answer and manual answer?

Gaussian distribution formula

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expressions for `a` and `b` are wrong. Should be

```
a=1/(Math.sqrt(2*Math.PI))/sigm2;
b= Math.exp(-0.5*Math.pow((x-mu)/sigm2,2));
```

Comment: That doesn't change the output. It is still 0.7259121735574301.